# Templated class does no compile using the latest intel compiler

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, stdarray

The following snippet compiles using the intel icc 2021.2.0 and clang without any warning. But it does not compile icc 2021.3.0 or gcc 11.1 throwing the error

```
#include <array>

class Base {
  public:
    enum Types { Al, Mg };
    static constexpr unsigned int P = 2;
    static constexpr unsigned int bin_Al = 1;
    static constexpr unsigned int bin_Mg = 300;

    static constexpr std::array<unsigned int, P> bins{bin_Al, bin_Mg}; 
    Base();
};

template <typename Base::Types pNo>
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived();
  public:
    static std::array<double, bins[pNo]> particle_radii;
};

template <typename Base::Types pNo>
std::array<double, Base::bins[pNo]> Derived<pNo>::particle_radii;
```

Error:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'std::array<double, pNo->Base::bins.std::array<unsigned int, 2>::operator[]()> Derived<pNo>::particle_radii'
23 | std::array<double, Base::bins[pNo]> Derived<pNo>::particle_radii;

note: previous declaration as 'std::array<double, pNo->Base::bins.std::array<unsigned int, 2>::operator[]()> Derived<pNo>::particle_radii'
19 |     static std::array<double, bins[pNo]> particle_radii;
```

Here is the [godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/nW93c3Pja) example.

If I change the `std::array` to a POD double array, it compiles fine.

Can somebodt explain me why this is not compiling using some compilers?

Comment: It also compiles when you refer to `Base::bins` explicitly, but I don't really know why: https://godbolt.org/z/8qxEz81hW

Comment: `Base::Types` is not dependent. No need for `typename Base::Types`

Comment: clang and msvc both accept the same code so it's likely to be a GCC bug

Comment: `pNo->Base::bins.std::array<unsigned int, 2>::operator[]()` looks strange.

Comment: Try splitting `Base::bins[pNo]` off into its own constant.